# Set file name for unloaded file from Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am unloading snowflake data into external AWS S3 stg using the below command,

```
copy into '@ext_stg/path/file_name' 
from schema.table
file_format = (type=csv  field_delimiter= '~' compression='gzip' null_if=('','NULL', 'null',' ') field_optionally_enclosed_by= '"' )
OVERWRITE = TRUE
;
```

I want the unloaded filename to be **file_name.csv.gz**.

But what I am actually getting from the above code is, `file_name_0_3_0.csv.gz`

How do i set the desired filename as **file_name.csv.gz**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting `SINGLE=TRUE MAX_FILE_SIZE=5000000000` gave me the desired output. Thank you @waldente

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are trying to specify the csv extension twice. Try removing it from the S3 path, because the file extension is already specified in file_format.

copy into '@ext_stg/path/file_name<strike>**.csv**</strike>'

from schema.table

file_format = (type=**csv**  field_delimiter= '~' compression='gzip' null_if=('','NULL', 'null',' ') field_optionally_enclosed_by= '"' )

OVERWRITE = TRUE
;

Comment: Thanks. I am still getting _0_3_0 getting appended to filename. How to fix that?

Comment: Try `SINGLE=TRUE MAX_FILE_SIZE=5000000000` before the semicolon